# Android Studio: Adding a dependency to my Android Library

Tags: android, dependencies, android-studio

After adding a dependency to my Android Library from my app in android studio I receive many errors of the following kind.

[image]

My App module is dependent on my InterstitialAdLib android library.

[image]

Comment: One has caps in the package name and the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @Nebu, you should add your remark as an answer so I can mark it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has caps in the package name and the other doesn't.